# Player is not moving toward target without unity built in functions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector

I am trying to move my target object towards my player using custom codes(without built-in function of unity like MoveTowards)

```
Vector3 displacment = target.transform.position - player.transform.position;
//you can also get magnitude directly through displacement.magnitude
float xMagnitude = displacment.x * displacment.x;
float yMagnitude = displacment.y * displacment.y;
float zMagnitude = displacment.z * displacment.z;

float customMagnitude =Mathf.Sqrt(xMagnitude + yMagnitude + zMagnitude);
directionToMove = new Vector3(displacment.x / customMagnitude, displacment.y / customMagnitude, displacment.z / customMagnitude);
//directionToMove = displacment.normalized;
Vector3 velocity = directionToMove *  speed;
Vector3 moveAmount = velocity * Time.deltaTime;
target.transform.position += moveAmount;
```

I first got the displacement between two vectors than i get its direction and pass it to my position with speed. but its direction is not towards the player. what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Any reason why you don't use Unity built-in functions ?

Comment: because i want to learn vector math

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So let me get this straight: You want to move the target towards the player, not the player towards the target. Is this correct?

If you want to move the target object towards the player, then the displacement should be player.transform.position - target.transform.position, not the other way around.

If you really don't want to use the Unity functions, then here's how I would do your code:

```
Vector3 displacment = player.transform.position - target.transform.position;
float xMagnitude = displacment.x * displacment.x;
float yMagnitude = displacment.y * displacment.y;
float zMagnitude = displacment.z * displacment.z;

float customMagnitude =Mathf.Sqrt(xMagnitude + yMagnitude + zMagnitude);

//multiplying vector by scalar works the same,
//and is more readable (possibly faster too)
directionToMove = displacement * 1f/customMagnitude;

Vector3 velocity = directionToMove *  speed;
Vector3 moveAmount = velocity * Time.deltaTime;
target.transform.position += moveAmount;
```

Comment: Thanks for a answer

Answer (score 1):

If you want to move your target **towards** the player, the `displacment` must be :

```
displacment = player.transform.position - target.transform.position;
```

To generate a vector given the initial point : A (x1, y1, z1) and final point B (x2, y2, z2) the calculation is the following :

```
v = B - A = (x2 - x1, y2 - y1, z2 - z1);
```